# Recursively defining a list in python, all in the list are replaced by the last item

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists, powerset

I've just started working with Python, and I just came across some behavior that I don't understand. I've searched the site for an explanation, but I haven't been able to find it. Perhaps I don't know the right keywords to search.

I (think I)'m trying to define a list recursively, but in stead of repeatedly appending a new item to the list, all items in the list get replaced by this new item.  See the snippet below. The code is supposed to generate a list `I` containing all (ordered) sublists of `[0,...,n]` of length `d`.

```
n = 5
d = 2

def next(S):
    m = S.index(min([s for s in S if s+1 not in S]))
    for i in range(m):
        S[i] = i
    S[m] += 1
    return S

I = [[i for i in range(d)]]
while I[-1][0] <= n-d:
    I += [next(I[-1])]
print(I)
```

I expected this to return the following list:

```
[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[0,3],[1,3],[2,3],[0,4],[1,4],[2,4],[3,4],[0,5],[1,5],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5]]
```

But in stead it returns the following list:

```
[[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5],[4,5]]
```

Can anyone point me to an explanation as to why this code does not do what I expect it to? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output vs. actual output?

Comment: Does `I += [next(I[-1][:])]` help?

Comment: @Servaes I'd suggest using better variable names so it's easier to understand what you're trying to achieve. Also, next() is a built-in function, overriding that namespace could have undesired results.

Comment: @Servaes To answer your question, any change you make to the list `S` inside of `next` are reflected in your original list `I`, because `S` and `I` are list-references which refer to the same underlying list in memory. @Scott Hunter's solution navigates around this issue by passing a shallow-copy of `I` to each call of `next`, so that any changes made to `S` in `next` are not reflected in the original list `I`.

Answer (score 3):

Each call to `next` should get its own *copy* of the list; for example

```
I += [next(I[-1][:])]
```

Your code was building a list with multiple references *to the same list*.  By sending each call to `next` its own copy, all of the elements in the result are distinct.

This could also have been accomplished by changing `next` to build a new list from scratch instead of modifying the list it is passed.

Comment: yes, this works because [:] creates a copy of the array

Comment: @Servaes the issue you were having is that you though you were adding new elements to the array every time, but in fact you were changing all the previous elements as well. your `next` function is "destructive" it changes the input which is a **mutable**

Answer (score 0):

Your function `next()` alters the list it is given in-place, instead of creating a new copy. This is why all items in `I` are actually just the same list.

A statement like `S = list(S)` in `next()` would be sufficient to replace `S` with a (shallow) copy and ensure that changes to it are not applied to the original list.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a reference to an existing list rather than a copy of the list, so the list is modified as you iterate. The following might help explain this behavior:

```py
def modify(li, i=3):
    print(li)
    li += [i]  # This adds to the passed list
    if i > 0:
        modify(li, i-1)

def modify_copy(li, i=3):
    print(li)
    li = li + [i]  # This overwrites "li" on every call
    if i > 0:
        modify_copy(li, i-1)

one = [4]
modify(one)
print("Result:", one)

two = [4]
modify_copy(two)
print("Result:", two)
```

Output

```
[4]
[4, 3]
[4, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
Result: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[4]
[4, 3]
[4, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
Result: [4]
```